# How to keep my original dict when doing addition of Counter

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, counter

To my understanding, I know when I invoke `Counter` to covert dict. This dict includes value of keys is zero will disappear.

```
from collections import Counter

a = {"a": 1, "b": 5, "d": 0}
b = {"b": 1, "c": 2}

print Counter(a) + Counter(b)
```

If I want to keep my keys, how to do?

This is my expected result:

```
Counter({'b': 6, 'c': 2, 'a': 1, 'd': 0})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use the [`update()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update) method of Counter instead of `+` operator, example -

```
>>> a = {"a": 1, "b": 5, "d": 0}
>>> b = {"b": 1, "c": 2}
>>> x = Counter(a)
>>> x.update(Counter(b))
>>> x
Counter({'b': 6, 'c': 2, 'a': 1, 'd': 0})
```

`update()` function adds counts instead of replacing them , and it does not remove the zero value one either. We can also do `Counter(b)` first, then update with `Counter(a)`, Example -

```
>>> y = Counter(b)
>>> y.update(Counter(a))
>>> y
Counter({'b': 6, 'c': 2, 'a': 1, 'd': 0})
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, when summing two counter, only elements with a positive count are used.

If you want to keep the elements with a count of zero, you could define a function like this:

```
def addall(a, b):
    c = Counter(a)          # copy the counter a, preserving the zero elements
    for x in b:             # for each key in the other counter
        c[x] += b[x]        # add the value in the other counter to the first
    return c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just subclass `Counter` and adjust its `__add__` method:

```
from collections import Counter


class MyCounter(Counter):
    def __add__(self, other):
        """Add counts from two counters.
        Preserves counts with zero values.

        >>> MyCounter('abbb') + MyCounter('bcc')
        MyCounter({'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'a': 1})
        >>> MyCounter({'a': 1, 'b': 0}) + MyCounter({'a': 2, 'c': 3})
        MyCounter({'a': 3, 'c': 3, 'b': 0})
        """
        if not isinstance(other, Counter):
            return NotImplemented
        result = MyCounter()
        for elem, count in self.items():
            newcount = count + other[elem]
            result[elem] = newcount
        for elem, count in other.items():
            if elem not in self:
                result[elem] = count
        return result


counter1 = MyCounter({'a': 1, 'b': 0})
counter2 = MyCounter({'a': 2, 'c': 3})

print(counter1 + counter2)  # MyCounter({'a': 3, 'c': 3, 'b': 0})
```

Answer (score 0):

I help `Anand S Kumar` to do more a additional explanation.

Even though your dict includes negative value, it still keep your keys.

```
from collections import Counter

a = {"a": 1, "b": 5, "d": -1}
b = {"b": 1, "c": 2}

print Counter(a) + Counter(b)
#Counter({'b': 6, 'c': 2, 'a': 1})

x = Counter(a)
x.update(Counter(b))
print x
#Counter({'b': 6, 'c': 2, 'a': 1, 'd': -1})
```